# Maven throws IllegalCharsetNameException when compiling

Tags: java, maven

When I compile my code with Maven I get the following error.

Can someone please explain why this happens and help me solve it?

My error :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.269 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-13T13:59:38+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/307M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project panima: Fatal error compiling: CompilerException: IllegalCharsetNameException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: There is probably more information above the lines of output you posted. Can you please look if there is more related to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your compiler encoding property is lacking, try adding the following in your pom;

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

[Details of encoding property of maven compiler plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding)